# Xcode added Default-568@2x.png

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, xcode7

About a week ago xcode showed me some error and when I clicked to solve the problem, xcode added this picture:
[image]

My questions are: What is it good for? Why do I need it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you must include one.

From [Apple's Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/)

> To enhance the user’s experience at app launch, you must provide at least one launch image. A launch image looks very similar to the first screen your app displays. iOS displays this image instantly when the user starts your app and until the app is fully ready to use. As soon as your app is ready for use, your app displays its first screen, replacing the launch placeholder image.

Answer (score 1):

Without this default image (or a LaunchScreen storyboard), your app would not take all the available screen space on iPhones with 4" displays (iPhone 5, 5s, SE). This is the default image that those iPhones would use.
Of course you can (should!) change it with the one you designed.

Answer (score 1):

Runtime, leading to the top and bottom of applications were empty out a lot , because the application is based on a 320x480 size to run.